# Convert pcl to image

Tags: printer-control-language

I'm communicating with a logic analyzer (HP 1660A) over RS232. I issue a command which tells the analyzer to print screen its display and send it over to the controller (my pc) through serial communication. I'm saving the result (which is usually abut 25kB) to my computer and I would like to view it as a TIFF or other format. The problem is that the response from the analyzer comes in PCL format, therefore suitable to be sent to a printer and printed directly, but not to be opened as an image. I have tried a few PCL to image converters to do the job, I found one which does it properly, however I've used the trial version and I am reluctant to purchase it. I've given you the background of my labour. I would appreciate any kind of help, a reference to the commands in pcl 1 and what should I do in order to extract the data and format it properly from the PCL file. I have no experience with PCL and image processing whatsoever, so please, give me a hand here. Thank you.

P.S. I've obtained the PCL file from the analyzer, both in C# and matlab... I have one slight problem in C# with the serial port control, some images have some uninterpreted characters in the image, when using the above converters. I say all these because I need an algorithm or some indications, no matter the programming language, so please feel free to post.

Answer (score 3):

PCL is complex to read.  There are only a handful of tools out there that do a good job of this.  We have lots of PCL expertise and still often look to other to supply conversion to PDF and other formats.  If the PCL is quite simple, that is, just text, a few fonts, and a graphic or two, a couple of RegEx commands could deal with the extraction of the text and then you could mock up a new document using whatever tools you wish.

Looking at these files in stackoverflow might be tough.  If you can get them on an ftp and post a link I can take a quick look and post my findings/thoughts here.  The other option is to look to an outside tool.  There are a few we've had success with.  Our needs are broad so I've settled on one that works the best with many different PCL streams (some PCL coding is better than others).  As you are dealing with a known quantity of PCL you may have a few options.  Here are a few we've used and had some success with (in order of usefulness to us)

[PCLWorks by PageTech](http://www.pclworks.com) (they have a GUI viewer and complete SDK)

[VeryPDF PCL Converter](http://www.verypdf.com/pcltools/index.html) (command line tool)

[SwiftView](http://www.swiftview.com/swiftconvert.htm)

There are others, and even an opensource variant of Ghostscript that handles PCL (we've never had much luck as the PCL we use often contains very custom fonts, symbol sets, and tons of macros which seem to choke it.

[GhostPCL](http://www.ghostscript.com/)

**EDIT:** Most recently we've been working with LincPDF (http://www.lincolnco.com/).  This is also an excellent product with has one big benefit, deployment is simple.  Some of the other tools have complex software installations.  This solution is very easy for us to deploy as a feature in an application.  It's also faster then any tools we've tested to date (at least with the PCL that we generate from our apps which is quite complex as they include specialized fonts and macros).

Comment: I suggest looking elsewhere than PCLWorks. It may have once been a descent product, but the product looks like it's from the 70's and support from BP is quite lacking. I am still looking for a descent product if anyone knows of one.

Answer (score 0):

According to the spec sheet for the HP 1660 ([pdf](http://cp.literature.agilent.com/litweb/pdf/5963-2172E.pdf)) series can send the TIFF,PCX and postscript.

Wouldn't it be easier to use TIFF?

Answer (score 0):

The project was put on hold for a while, but I would like to offer a complete and usable solution.

@Adrian
You can save the image to a floppy disk, I've done that, saved it as TIFF and everything worked fine. Unfortunately, it sends only PCL through RS232. The idea to save the print screen over serial communication was to avoid using too much the floppy disk, which the device uses in order to boot.

@Douglas
Thank you for your elaborate answer. I'll take a look at the indicated tools, however, my desire is to offer a complete front-end solution, which yields directly the graphic. I've put some files from my tests [here](http://s10.transfer.ro/storage/transfer_ro-eee1fab3315cf2bbc75a.zip) in order to see the complexity of the PCL constructions. Do you have any knowledge of a possible API that I could integrate into my application, which can parse the file and interpret the PCL?

Regards,
Cosmin

Answer (score 0):

We capture the serial input via a serial spooler that watches COM1:.  It's called SSpool.exe.  It redirects the PCL as input to PCLXForm.  PCLXForm converts it into any raster format (TIFF, JPG, PDF, BMP, etc.)  However, we can also extract the text during the conversion and we can extract individual raster objects from the PCL for re-arrangement in the downstream application.  Our pricing model is positioned for licensee's that need to convert up to 50,000 pages of invoices into indexed PDF's per month.  However, this type of application normally requires a custom license in order to get our pricing down to the level required.  In order to do so, we often have to restrict our product to convert unlimited files, but only up to the 20th page within any one PCL print file.  That provides enough page volume and gives us the ability to reduce the pricing per unit.  To demo, you would need the PCLTool SDK.