# PDF417 image to Pcl conversion in java code without any software installation

Tags: java, printer-control-language

I have prn file and my requirement is to dynamically generate PDF 417 2D barcode for that prn and pass it to HP Laser printer.

I don't find any java API to generate 2D barcode(PDF417)to PCL directly. so I have converted 2D barcode to Image file using barcode4j framework now i am trying to convert that image to PCL format.

I could find software / online converter for Image to PCL but not Java API.

Is there any Java API and soft fonts? if not how can i write it on my own.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/492267/1168680